# WHERE clause behaving in the wrong way

Tags: mysql

i want to create a weekly report using a php script. in the mysql query of this, i want to take out tables that functioned during the last week by using its timestamp in the meantime get the other values(especially the counts of unique users and overall users) since the creation date of those tables. but at the moment its returning incorrect data in terms of counts where the counts are given only within the last week not since the creation of project.

**this happens inside a loop so for the example query im using table table_1**

**QUERY**

```
SELECT  DISTINCT b.ID, name, accountname, c.accountID, status,
        total_impr, min(a.timestamp), max(a.timestamp),COUNT(DISTINCT userid)
        AS unique_users,COUNT(userid) AS overall_users
FROM    table_1 a INNER JOIN logs b on a.ID = b.ID INNER JOIN
        accounts c on b.accountID = c.accountID

WHERE   a.timestamp > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 WEEK
```

Comment: `DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 WEEK)` will give last week data only

Comment: can i manipulate these... in some way and fullfill my requirement

Comment: You should use two queries. One is for last week data only, and the other is for data of all period.